# Cannot access local server via IP address but it can via its computer name

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a server in my local network that is part of a Windows Server 2012 domain.

I can access the server's shared folder via its name but I can't via its IP address.

Comment: Did you use \\IPAddress\ ?

Comment: Yes and the problem is related to my PC not my server, because i can reach \\myserver and \\ip from other PC's

Comment: The error is: \\myip is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

Account restrictions are preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank passwords aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has been enforced.

Comment: Such a situation may be resolved by a restart of the affected PC, in the case something changed in the credentials.

Comment: I reset my PC but still can't access \\192.168.1.88 :(

Comment: I try \\192.168.1.88\share but windows keep asking for password, even after i entered correct user and password

Comment: Just to be sure: what does a nslookup on the server name give you?

Comment: nslookup give 192.168.1.88 IP, in fact I can't access any other PC's in my LAN via IP, but can with PC name

Comment: try to disable firewall on target PC

Comment: Is there a policy that prevents NTLM authentication. leaving Kerberos as the only option? Kerberos does not support connecting to an IP address, only by machine name.

Comment: Thaks a lot Gert Jan Kraaijeveld! That was the problem

Comment: Gert, great deduction. You should write that as an actual answer as it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Gert comment:
There a policy that prevents NTLM authentication. The problem was leaving Kerberos as the only option Kerberos does not support connecting to an IP address, only by machine name.